# Cannot load web pages from apache2

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

While setting up a dev environment in a VM running Ubuntu Server 14.04.1, I am unable to load any web page. I have a custom config file for loading files from a shared folder (easier development) like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName sandbox
      ServerAlias *.dev

      LogLevel info
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev-error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev-access.log combined

      RewriteEngine On

      <Directory />
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
      </Directory>

      <Directory /media/>
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          Require all granted
      </Directory>

      <Location /server-status>
          SetHandler server-status
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          Require all granted
      </Location>

      UseCanonicalName Off
      VirtualDocumentRoot /media/sf_%1
</VirtualHost>
```

The config is enabled and properly symlinked using `a2ensite`, and both the rewrite, status, and vhost modules are enabled with `a2enmod`, and I have tried changing the group ownership to `www-data`. What have I misconfigured?

EDIT: There is no error, however a 404 is returned upon entering the site

Comment: I'm not familiar with vhost module, but i think you missed a `Require all granted` under `<Directory />`. Also did you restarted after enabling mods and sites?, what the error log shows?

Answer (score 0):

So I feel like a fool... As @bistoco said

> I think you missed a `Require all granted` under `<Directory />`.

That, along with using the correct directory name, was the solution. It wasn't `/media/sf_%1` but `/mnt/hgfs/sandbox.dev`...